# How to find the limit? (ratio test or limit comparison test?)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{5^n}{n!+4^n}\right)$$

I know it tends to $0$ but I don't know how to show it? I've tried using the ratio test but I don't know where to go from
$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{5\left(n!+4^n\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!+4^{n+1}}$$

Comment: Hint: the $n$ factors of $n!$ are growing linearly, while those of the powers are constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the ratio test to conclude that
$$\lim_n \frac{5^n}{n!}=0$$
and then apply the squeeze theorem to
$$0 \le \frac{5^n}{n!+4^n}\le \frac{5^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 1):

$n! \geq 6^{n-5}$ for all $n \geq 6$. Then let us just consider the terms after 6.

Then $0\leq \frac{5^n}{n!+4^n} \leq \frac{5^n}{6^{n-5}+4^n} \leq \frac{5^n}{6^{n-5}}=6^5 \cdot\frac{n^5}{n^{6}}=6^5 \cdot(\frac{5}{6})^n$.

But we also know that $\lim_{n \to \infty}6^5\cdot (\frac{5}{6})^n=0$,
and so we can just use the squeeze theorem from here.

Comment: The downside to this kind of approach though, is that your limit is going to zero *much* faster than $(\frac{5}{6})^n$, so you miss a lit bit of intuition. In general $n!$ grows much faster than an exponential function.

Answer (score 1):

For $n> 5,$
$$0<\frac{5^n}{n!+4^n} < \frac{5^n}{n!} = \frac{5^5}{5!}\frac{5}{6}\frac{5}{7}\cdots\frac{5}{n} \le \frac{5^5}{5!}\frac{5}{n}.$$

The last expression $\to 0$ so the desired limit is $0.$

Answer (score 0):

By the Stirling approximation $$n!\sim(n/e)^n$$ or by more elementary considerations $$(n/3)^n<n!<(n/2)^n.$$ Which should show what is the fastest growing term in that expression.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up where the OP left off, it's obvious that

$${5(n!+4^n)\over(n+1)!+4^{n+1}}\lt{5(n!+4^n)\over(n+1)!}$$

so all it takes is a crude upper bound on $4^n$ that facilitates some cancellation.  The inequality

$$4^n=4\cdot4\cdots4\cdot4\cdot4\lt n(n-1)\cdots4(4\cdot3)(4\cdot2)(4\cdot1)=64n!$$

will more than suffice.  It gives

$${5(n!+4^n)\over(n+1)!+4^{n+1}}\lt{5(n!+4^n)\over(n+1)!}\lt{325n!\over(n+1)!}={325\over n+1}$$